# Are ostinatos and motifs essentially the same thing?

Tags: piano, motif

I understand that there is a difference between the two, but I'm still confused. Are the terms "ostinato" and "motif" interchangeable?

Comment: An ostinato repeats multiple times *without interruption*. A motif can appear basically at any time in any place.

Comment: Also: "ostinato" has a fairly narrow and concrete definition. "Motif" has a fairly fuzzy and vague one, meaning little more than "a recognizable unit." You could use "motif" in talking about visual art to mean a certain visual element, but you couldn't use "ostinato" except as a metaphor referring to the musical meaning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. An ostinato is a sustained pattern, lasting many bars. A motif is a particular 'musical idea', that may itself last several bars, which keeps re-occurring during a piece.

An ostinato is particularly a rhythmic pattern that is repeated bar after bar, or in two or four bar sequences. A motif will pop up from time to time to remind us of itself.

Comment: I think it would be good of you could make the difference between "sustained pattern" and "keeps re-occuring" more precise. (I have no idea what you mean)

Comment: Also, an obstinato brings along the idea that it repeats identically.  But a motif (also called a motive) is often developed and lengthened into a more substantial theme later

Comment: Examples: Beethoven's 5th: motif. Ravel's Bolero: ostinato.

Comment: @Andy that's Beethovens favorite fruit. "Banananaaaa"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmzER7X2424 my personal favorite ostinato.

Comment: @nuggethead - *obstinato* is maybe a better name!

Comment: Hi! @nuggethead, even you can find _obstinato_ in a few resources, the right term is ___ostinato___, as it comes directly from the italian word, which does not have any 'b' character. Please check https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ostinato as an example (from Enciclopedia Italiana di Scienze, Lettere e Arti)

Comment: Twas a typo.  I cant seem to edit the comment to fix it

Comment: @nuggethead - seems comments can't be edited after 5 mins. So either scrap that one and write another, or leave it. I quite like it, thought it was quite clever! Somewhat apposite.

Answer (score 6):

No. They serve very different purposes.

A motif starting on a different note of the scale or in a different mode is still the same motif. Motives are defined by their melodic contour.

An ostinato repeats without variation, even when it clashes with the underlying harmony.